# Create iOS App without code sign , stuck installing app

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, codesign

I just make simple app for iOS , just show label "Hello"
and i'm done to set code sign required to "NO" in build settings
and then go to Products -> Archive , the app has build successfully and generate .ipa file ,
the problem is , when i install my app from itunes to my iOS device and Sync it , the app stuck on "Installing" , i don't have any idea for this , 
Can anyone help me about this? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code signing your app assures users that it is from a known source and the app hasn’t been modified since it was last signed. Before your app can integrate app services, be installed on a device, or be submitted to the App Store, it must be signed with a certificate issued by Apple.

Without code signing the device will not allow the app to install.

If your device is jailbroken then follow the below link for self signing certificate.

https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/9r8j2n/question_installing_apps_to_a_jailbroken_iphone/

Comment: hmm , can i make my own code signing without using developer code sign on apple ? maybe fake it ? cause i just make and use my app on my own device , btw my device is iphone 5s with jailbroken(8.4) is that possible ?

Comment: Thank you :) i just open that link and look promising, i will try it , thank you!